# An infinite sequence with discontinuities though uniformly convergent $\forall x$

Tags: real-analysis

So in Taylor and Mann's *Advanced Calculus*, there's an example of checking uniform convergence of the geometric series using the Weierstrass M-test:

$u_n(x)=x^n\ ,\ M_n=r^n$. They conclude that since $|x|\le r$ and $|u_n(x)|\le M_n$ and also that $\sum r^n$ is a convergent series, $\sum u_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent on the interval $-r 
\le x \le r$ if $0 <r<1.$
 But it's not convergent on the *closed* interval ($0\le r \le 1$) since $1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$.

With this example in mind, I was working showing the following is uniformly convergent:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos\left(\left(2x+1\right)x\right)}{(n+1)(n)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$$

It's clear that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n)(n+1)}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$$

And it's known that the RHS is convergent so the LHS is uniformly convergent on some interval.

The answer for the interval is all $x$, but i'm wondering why that is? since if we look at the books example the interval doesn't seem like it should be all $x$ when there are points of discontinuity.

Comment: When you say that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos\left(\left(2x+1\right)x\right)}{(n+1)(n)}\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n)(n+1)},$$ where are you quantifying $x$? If you're doing it over $\Bbb R$, then W.M-test will give you convergence for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: First part was meant to be _closed_, and I was just making a shorthand version of the sequence so I didn't have to type it again.

Comment: I edited my comment above as I feel like that particular question wasn't answered yet.

Comment: @GitGud: Ah, I see what you meant. Well, it doesn't specify, it just asks me to stat what range of values of $x$ I'm making the assertion for.

Comment: Another question: regarding the very last sentence in the question, it sort of seems like you're implying that there are points of discontinuity regarding the $f_n$ at hand. That is not the case. For all $n\in \Bbb N$ and for all $x\in \Bbb R$, $f_n$ is continuous at $x$. Are you aware of this?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. It's basically just that example problem that made me think there was something wrong.

Comment: The thing with the example is that you can't make the inequality $|u(x)|\leq M_n$ true for all $x\in \Bbb R$, not even for all $x\in [0,1\textbf{]}$. But it is true for all $x\in \textbf{]}0,1[$. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, I see now! Thank you! If you want to write a short answer I can accept it for you.

Comment: Done. Thanks. Good luck with your finals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on the discussion on the comments, it was clarified that the OP was having trouble understanding why sometimes the W. M-test works for all $x\in \Bbb R$ while other times just for a *short* interval.

In the example stated in the book the inequality $|u(x)|\leq M_n$ isn't true for all $x\in \Bbb R$, not even for all $x\in [0,1\textbf{]}$. But it is true for all $x\in \textbf{]}0,1[$. Hence W. M-test guarantees the convergence in $\textbf{]}0,1[$ but not in any other set strictly containing $\textbf{]}0,1[$.

Regarding the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos\left(\left(2x+1\right)x\right)}{(n+1)(n)}$, since the inequality $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ (as noted by the OP) is true for all $x\in \Bbb R$, the W. M-test guaranteers the convergence in $\Bbb R$.